# Programing Raspberry Pi with Pi4j Embedded Linux JVM. Run button disabled

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I have been trying to configure [Embedded Linux JVM Debugger](https://github.com/asebak/embeddedlinux-jvmdebugger-intellij) with Intellij IDEA on my windows 10 PC. I have followed given instructions and I just cant run aplication becouse Run button is disabled.

I have installed Pi4J on my Windows PC throgh graddle dependency

```
    compile group: 'com.pi4j', name: 'pi4j-core', version: '1.1'
```

and [Pi4j Project](http://pi4j.com/install.html) on my Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry 3

Here is screenshot:

As you can see Connection Status: Success

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: On IJ 14 I don't have the `Run` button, but when I press `Apply`, the `Cancel` button changes to `Close`. If you press `Close`, can you use the `Run` button from the toolbar (or `Shift` + `F10` by default)?

Comment: No I can't. It shows me Box where i need to choose Run Configuration. And there is no Embded Linux JVM avalible to choose.

Comment: Oh, I missed something from the screenshot... duh! .You're configuring the defaults for this types of configuration instead of defining a configuration. Try adding a new config by pressing the green `+` (plus) in the upper left corner of the screen :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're configuring the default setting for all run configurations, instead of defining a run configuration. That's why you don't see anything in the drop-down list. That's fine if you want to have something already pre-configured, but you need to define your run configuration using the green `+` icon in the upper left corner:

[image: Run configurations]

Comment: You should get Oscar award for this presentation. Works! Thanks