# IntelliJ IDEA not saving JBoss Run Configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, deployment, jboss, war

I am trying to save a Run Configuration in IntelliJ IDEA with JBoss, but it is not being saved even if I press `Apply` and `OK`. Any hint?

Comment: how did you configure??

Comment: I followed this video from minute 2:16 to 3:00 aprox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3nnjmK1GwE

Comment: not saving means it gets disappeared after one run or exit intellij or any other??

Comment: not saving means, simply, not saving. I save it but the Run Configuration does not appear

Comment: In this video it is using Glass Fish not JBoss right?? So u r using JBoss or Glass Fish??

Comment: tried it with both them

Comment: Are you perhaps making the same simple mistake as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817029/programing-raspberry-pi-with-pi4j-embedded-linux-jvm-run-button-disabled/38829799#38829799)?